# How to create Android Application with offline for website?

Tags: android, offlineapps

I created an app for news. It accesses data from a website using the **JSON** concept. It's working fine.
Unfortunately when it's offline there's nothing to display. That's why I want to create the **App for Offline use** as well.

I have two ideas:

1.Create **SQLite database** and store the data when online. When the app  goes offline use that data.

2.**Store** the web data as a .txt file on **sdcard** when online. When the app goes offline use that data.

The website has more categories and sections.

Is there any other way to implement an **Offline App**? If so please tell me about it.

Comment: go with SQLite database. We have used it in past and works pefect with html display etc

Answer (score 0):

Use volley library to handle network related service and for offline you have use cache which is also feature of volley library

[enter link description here](http://mobilewebwizard.in/2015/01/offline-caching-with-volley-using-cache-controlled-header/)

Answer (score 0):

you could create categories in the database , and store data in the db

when the user is online you can check the date and compare with  stored date to update your app , for images you can use lazy loading, downlaod the data by parsing the rss or xml feeds of the website

Comment: website have more categories and sections

Comment: you can create a main db with the details of sections and categories and download data as per your requirement

Comment: this example will help you http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/android-rss-reader-application-using-sqlite-part-1/

Comment: no i need alternative method for database.because website have large database. i can't create in large db in local.

Comment: the db limit, will be the one available on your(user's) phone, the better way would be to have an online rss reader without downloading any data permanently or keep updating the data daily